# Ubuntu Server 10.10 vs. Fedora Server 14 for Mono.NET app hosting in VM

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, virtual-machines, fedora, mono

Ubuntu Server 10.10 vs. Fedora Server 14

I want to create a web-server running Mono, MySQL 5.5 and OpenLDAP running as a VM (on VMWare Workstation).

Searching “Ubuntu Server  vs. Fedora Server” mostly yields flame wars and noise. There are a few good articles available but they are either out-of-date or don’t offer very convincing arguments.

I know the answer is most likely to be “it depends” but I wanted to harness the collective wisdom on ServerFault and get opinions, experiences and factual information to the extent possible.

My selection criteria would be (other than what is mentioned above):

1. Ease of use
2. Ease of development
3. Reliability
4. Security

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The distributions you list are not server focused. They're general-purpose enough that they'll *work*, but, crucially, you will need to plan to upgrade them on a shorter timeframe than is usually ideal for a server (13 months for Fedora, 18 for Ubuntu), and update churn within a releas may be higher than ideal.

Unless you can reasonably plan for that, you should look at either an [Ubuntu LTS](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS) release (like 10.04), which will be supported for five years for server use, or at Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6, which is derived from Fedora and is supported for a decade or so. If cost or license-tracking is an issue, the CentOS rebuild (not yet out for RHEL 6) is a bit-for-bit compatible option as well, with the same support lifetime but an inevitable short delay in security updates.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have been reading about Ubuntu 10.4 LTS and it seems to be the answer.

Answer (score 2):

It makes no difference. Practically any mono package for Ubuntu is also available for Fedora, including MonoDevelop.

Keep in mind that Fedora is on a six month release cycle and each release gets end-of-life after two more new releases. So F14 will have *no more updates after F16 comes out* in about a year. Ubuntu, on the other hand, has a longer cycle.

If you want a Fedora-like distribution with a longer cycle, use [CentOS](http://www.centos.org/).

Update: Ubuntu LTS is the variant with a longer release cycle. Read mattdm's comment.

Comment: Note that Ubuntu's non-LTS lifecycle is only marginally longer.

Answer (score 1):

I can only tell you why I choose Ubuntu Server among other distribution:

- Ubuntu is probably (one of) the most popular linux distribution with huge user base, therefore most of the problems which you can run into are (probably) solved
- big portion of mono users/developers/deployers choose Ubuntu because of it's popularity and upper fact, therefore there is a big chance of a possible mono related problems being solved on this distribution
- MonoDevelop have package for Ubuntu
- IMHO reliability and security issues should be resolved faster because of big user base pressure (this is of course subjective and depends on situation)